# SQL Math operatos in where clause

Tags: sql, math, operators, where-clause

I would like to know if it's possible to get math operators in `WHERE` clause.

Example: I have a table with a `dataType` field name. This length can be different. 1527 or 152710 or 15271712...

Can I use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONVERT(INT, (dataType / 10000)) = 1527 LIMIT 10
```

PD: Nowaday I'm using:

```
... WHERE dataType BETWEEN (15270000 and 15279999)
```

filling the data entry with zeros, but it isn't really optimized. I mean:

```
... BETWEEN (15000000 and 15999999)
```

It's going to compare 1.000.000 of regs.

Comment: What database system do you use?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  Why didn't you just try it?

Comment: Yes, but flooring like that may not be as performant - using the upper/lower bounds is usually [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).  Oh, and please never use `BETWEEN`, it's almost always better to use an exclusive upper-bound (especially with things like timestamps).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mathematical Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html) available in MySql for that. `FLOOR` should work in your case:

```
.... WHERE FLOOR(dataType / 10000.0) = 1527
```

Comment: You're welcome! You're a new user, so just in case you don't know how StackOverflow works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)

Comment: it would have been great if you also answered the question title for us future readers